# Different results for choosing committee with at least two architects

Tags: combinatorics

A committee of four needs to be chosen from a group of 3 engineers, 5 economists and 4 architects. In how many ways (people are unique) can it be formed, such that there are at least 2 architects in it?

I have reasoned in two different ways and got different answers. Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

The first way is to **split the possibilities** into those with 2, 3 and 4 architects. This yields:

> $ C(4,2) \cdot C(8,2) + C(4,3) \cdot C(8,1) + C(4,4) \cdot C(8,0) = 201$

The other is to **choose first two architects** and then 2 people from the remaining 10:

> $ C(4,2) \cdot C(10,2) = 270$

One of this solutions was arrived at by other people, so I have reason to think that one is correct but I am not certain so I let it to you to resolve this matter. Thanks!

Also, if my interpretation is correct the second method is used [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593148/choosing-a-committee-combination-problem). What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is correct. The second method is not correct.

Letting $A,B,C,D$ be four architects, the second method counts a set $\{ABCD\}$ multiple times.

1) First you choose $AB$, then you choose $CD.$

2) First you choose $AC$, then you choose $BD$.

and so on...

Comment: Does that implies the solution to the other question also wrong?

Comment: What is the other question? the linked one?

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593148/choosing-a-committee-combination-problem)

Comment: Exactly, because it seems to me it uses the same flawed reasoning.

Comment: The answer is correct. Do you see the difference? The linked question is saying at least two in every group. This question we are talking about is saying at least two in a group. This is only one difference and big difference.

Comment: I thounght I did but I don't see how this makes a difference. I still think the same reasoning applies. The situation where you: "Choose NA and NB from Nebrasca. Choose two from each of the other two states. Choose NC from Nebrasca." is being counted separate from the one where you "Choose NB and NC from Nebraska, ..., choose NA from Nebrasca".

Comment: I don't know where this discussion should take place sorry if I am doing it wrong

Comment: Oh, sorry my mistake. The answer for the linked question is wrong. Let $ABCDEF$ in Nebraska, $GHIJKLM$ in Idaho, $NOPQRSTU$ in Louisiana. Then, $\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{7}{2}\cdot\binom{8}{2}\cdot\binom{15}{1}$ counts a set $\{ABGHNOF\}$ multiple times. 1) You choose $AB,GH, NO, F$. 2) You choose $AF, GH, NO, B$.